# Is it possible to redirect outgoing traffic on an already used port without using iptables?

Tags: linux, iptables, redirect, port

I am wondering is there is another solution than iptables to redirect outgoing traffic on a port that is already used to another one, on the same machine locally.

Thanks.

Comment: A Webserver can use one port to serve multiple destinations. but what do you want to solve?

Comment: This question looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).

Comment: On a Linux computer only locally, I want to redirect request that goes to a certain (used) port to a proxy port, and this proxy will then let the request go to its first destination port.
I succeed to do it with iptables, but I was wondering if there is another solution, potentially without sudo privilege but I guess it's not possible.